# Reprojection output too large when exporting an image to drive

Tags: export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to export an image in the GeoTIFF format to drive. The error is the following : Reprojection output too large.

I think this error can come from the fact that I'm resampling my ImageCollection several times :

The resample function to create a Landsat 8 dataset with the MODIS Aqua pixel size :

```
function resample(img){
  return img.reduceResolution({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  maxPixels : 65536
  })
  .reproject({
    crs : ModisProjection
  })
  .copyProperties(img)
}
```

The ImageCollection.reduceToImage to get the mean value of each pixel from the past 10 years :

```
var mean = Landsat_Modis.reduceToImage({
  properties : ["Chloa_OC3"],
  reducer : ee.Reducer.mean()})
```

It can also be because of the larger of my ROI, unfortunately I really need to clip my image over this area.

Can someone know how to deal with this error ?

Link to my code :
https://code.earthengine.google.com/1f65b50e6b44d64076547b505a6dae6a